# Htaccess always adds parameters in URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-parameters

I have domain parked to my main domain. I don't know why but it always adds the parameter when I do a redirection.

https://lgbtmilitary.org/
redirects to
https://delisoft.ca/expertise/marketing-lgbtq/?lang=fr&page=accueil&url=1
instead of just
https://delisoft.ca/expertise/marketing-lgbtq/

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.\*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} \[R,L\]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.\*
RewriteRule .\* ? \[F,L\]

ErrorDocument 404 https://delisoft.ca/plan-du-site/


# Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

# Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)

BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4.0\[678\] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \\bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
Header append Vary User-Agent
\</IfModule\>

RewriteRule ^$ index.php?lang=fr&page=accueil&url=1

RewriteRule ^expertise/strategie-web-b2b/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expb2b
RewriteRule ^expertise/strategie-web-b2c/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expb2c
RewriteRule ^expertise/construction/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expconstruction
RewriteRule ^expertise/professionnels-de-la-sante/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expsante
RewriteRule ^expertise/immobilier-site-web/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expimmobilier
RewriteRule ^expertise/site-web-esthetique/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=expbeauty
RewriteRule ^expertise/marketing-lgbtq/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=explgbtq&service=marketing
RewriteRule ^expertise/(\[a-z-A-Z0-9\]+)-lgbtq/$ index.php?lang=fr&page=explgbtq&service=$1

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# Set the “ea-php72” package as the default “PHP” programming language.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php72 .php .php7 .phtml

# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^lgbtmilitary.org$ \[OR\]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.lgbtmilitary.org$
RewriteRule ^(.\*)$ "https://delisoft.ca/expertise/marketing-lgbtq/" \[R=301,L\]
```

Comment: You have a rule that actually implements exactly that: `RewriteRule ^$ index.php?lang=fr&page=accueil&url=1`. That rule is executed _first_ , so requests to that domain only will get rewritten. _Then_ you check for the host name any try to redirect that. But at that point the request has already been rewritten.

Comment: You should move the redirection for that host name ("domain") up in the file, _above_ , right before the redirection to https. So that it gets executed _before_ the other rules get applied.